# отчётность (ReportViewer)

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

я создавал уже некоторую отчётность на одном листе(как в этом примере https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/hh273267(v=vs.140) ), но теперь мне необходимо создавать, таблицу с заранее неизвестным количеством строк, т.е. страниц м.б. больше чем 1. 
Вопрос: как формировать таблицу или что то похожее на неё? Или же, как можно перенести все данные из коллекции на ReportViewer.

Пробовал пройтись по этой ссылке:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/ms251784(v=vs.140)
но встрял на этапе добавления ReportViewer'a в toolBox, добавлял скаченные пакеты через Choose Item... , но получал отказ в виде "the following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer".

P.S. версии фрейма я подбирал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было просто добавлять строки в `DataTable`, но осознание этого пришло ко мне не сразу.